# Using RSpec to Test Console Application Interaction

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, console-application, read-eval-print-loop

I have several console applications that have a read, evaluate, print, loop (REPL) using readline that I would like to create tests for using RSpec if possible. I've read about mock classes, but I don't see how they would work. Is it only possible to replace a real input class to test the rest of the classes? I want to do an integration test of the whole app. For one of my web services, I have an rspec script that uses curl to send requests to test the socket interface. I wanted to do something similar for the console interface. Am I just not understanding the concept of mock classes?

### Answer

Based on the answer @Dave Schweisguth gave, I tried this:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'pty'

describe "anthematic" do
  before(:all) do
    @output, @input = PTY.spawn('bin/anthematic')
  end

  it "turns on a zone" do
    @output.readpartial 1024 # read past the prompt
    @input.puts "on 1"
    expect(@output.readline.chomp).to eq("on 1")
    expect(@output.readline.chomp).to eq("turn on zone 1")
  end
end
```

I moved the spawn out so I can add other tests. I'm new to rspec so that may not be the cleanest solution.

While researching PTY, I found [this article](https://devver.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/ruby-subprocesses-part_3/) on sub-processes that covers popen, pty, and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you that it would be good to have at least one or a few integration tests of the whole app. Those tests shouldn't have mocks; mocks replace dependencies of classes that you want to test in isolation. Here's a simple way to integration-test a command-line app, using irb as an example:

```
require 'pty'

describe "irb" do
  it "evaluates an expression" do
    PTY.spawn('irb') do |output, input|
      output.readpartial 1024 # read past the prompt
      input.puts "1 + 1"
      expect(output.readline.chomp).to eq("1 + 1")
      expect(output.readline.chomp).to eq("=> 2")
    end
  end
end
```

If I had more than one test like this I'd extract an RSpec matcher, but I left the nitty-gritty inline here to keep it simple.

This kind of test is relatively slow, since it runs the app in a separate process with a new Ruby instance, so you only want to write one or a few of these to test that the app works as a whole and then test the details with unit tests of individual classes. What those look like, and whether you need mocks, depends entirely on the internal structure of your app.

Comment: Dave Schweisguth,  your example hangs for me. I put the details in my question.

Comment: Try removing the first `stdout.readline`. That discards a line of irb output which your program won't have.

Comment: That change had no effect. I tried your code as is and it works. I'll read up on popen3 later today.

Comment: I changed my answer to use a pty, which works more naturally for irb. Possibly it will work better for you too.

Answer (score 0):

So the role of mocks in rspec tests are to stand in for method calls and give expected return values. So say in this case you have a class which makes a call to get a hash, but you don't want to actually make that call within your spec.

```
MyClass.get_info
```

or something like that.

In rpsec, what you can do is designate the return value/object/whatever for when that method is called. To do this, at the beginning of the spec or in a before do block you would put

```
allow(MyClass).to receive(:get_info).and_return({ key: 'value' })
```

Now within the spec, any calls to MyClass.get_info would return your designated hash.

```
my_info = MyClass.get_info
# my_info = { key: 'value' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically write a mock when something is too difficult to actually test or is too resource-intensive to test.

In this case, what you are trying to do (REPL testing) is difficult but not impossible.

I'm sure there are other ways to do it but here's the method I've used:

**Step 1** Write a shell command that pipes commands to your REPL program.

```
shell_cmd = %{(echo "MyClass.new.call_my_command"; echo "exit") | ruby my_repl_program.rb"}
```

This uses parenthesis to combine multiple "echo" outputs, then sends then to your program. Note that you *need* to send an exit command or else the process will hang.

**Step 2** call the shell command and set a variable to the output:

```
cmd_output = `#{shell_cmd}`
```

**Step 3** verify the output

Now you can test the value of `cmd_output` however you need.